# Edit Text and its curser position?

Tags: android

Is it possible in Edit Text view in android that we write the text in middle of the edit text view, like in MS Word. means that Writing alignment right,left our middle of the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In xml file Use: android:gravity="top | bottom | left | right | center"

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Set the gravity of the edittext to center.

Answer (score 0):

use public int `getSelectionStart ()` and public int `getSelectionEnd ()`, more on

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getSelectionStart()

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try this code:

```
editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

The cursor position part is missing in the body of the question - how is that relevant?

If you want to set the text centered statically you can use `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`

```
<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="1234" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:gravity="center_horizontal"></EditText>
```

will look like:
[image]

What is not quite clear in your question is if you want to have a mixture of alignments within one text field, so I assume that one alignment definition is sufficient